# Difference between a node being node != null and node.next == null?

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm reading up on linked lists [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Linked%20Lists/linked%20lists.html) and I'm kind of confused. I've drawn it out but it still looks like they are the same thing.

Traversing through a linked list:

```
Node tmp = head;
while(tmp != null) {
     tmp = tmp.next;
}
```

My thought process for the while loop: tmp starts at head. Now while tmp points to a next node, tmp moves on to pointing to the node next to it. And it goes on until tmp is not pointing to another node next to it.

Adding to the end of a linked list:

```
public void addLast(AnyType item)
{
   if(head == null) addFirst(item);
   else
   {
      Node<AnyType> tmp = head;
      while(tmp.next != null) 
            tmp = tmp.next;

      tmp.next = new Node<AnyType>(item, null);
   }
}
```

My thought process for the while loop: tmp starts at head. Now while tmp points to a next node, tmp moves on to pointing to the node next to it. And it goes on until tmp is not pointing to another node next to it. Then it breaks out of the loop and assigns tmp to point next to a new Node.

Comment: The best thing to do when you don't understand the code is step through it in your IDE Debugger, examining the variables at each step to see what changed. Most debuggers will even highlight changed variables at each step for you.

Comment: @JimGarrison what IDE do u suggest that does that?

Comment: Eclipse or NetBeans or IntelliJ

Comment: @JimGarrison I have IntelliJ! What do I do to step through my code tho? I just run the code.

Comment: @sukiyo Read and work throughout [debugging section](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging.htmll)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first loop using

> temp != null

you will iterate over the linked list and cross it completely. It can be useful in the case when you have to just print all the elements of linked list. But in case of adding a node in last, you have to stop at just the last node so you can append new node to the last.next node.

`temp.next != null` ensures that it will stop at last node where `temp.next is actually null`.
While using 1st you won't be able to stop at last node but while using 2nd you at just stopped where you have to append a new node i.e. at last otherwise you will pass over it.

Q. they are the same thing?

No, they aren't.

And the question's last paragraph is correct

> My thought process for the while loop: tmp starts at head. Now while tmp points to a next node, tmp moves on to pointing to the node next to it. And it goes on until tmp is not pointing to another node next to it. Then it breaks out of the loop and assigns tmp to point next to a new Node.

Now Adding to it, 1st case is where your **temp** itself will become **null**

Comment: thanks so much! what do you mean "your temp itself will become null"? Does that mean the data inside the temp?

Comment: @sukiyo you can say data inside temp will become null or if you know about reference variable or pointers, then in that language it will point to null. At null you won't be able to perform any action. So when you are at last node only you have add another node. It would be wrong and meaningless if you try to add a node to null

Answer (score 2):

Think about what `tmp` will be *after* the loop finishes. With `tmp != null`, `tmp` can *only* be `null`, which is useless; you can't do anything with a `null`.

After the loop, you want `tmp` to be the *last* node, so you can add the new node to it. All nodes but the last have a next node, so checking for `tmp.next != null` means when the loop exits, `tmp.next` will be `null`, which is only true for the last node.

The code would be clearer if the variable was named `last` (instead of `tmp`).

Answer (score 0):

long story short tmp.nxt basically check if there is a link connecting the next node .so in the iterative loop if there are n nodes then it will run n-1 times .
but node!=null will run n times cuz node!=null is checking the existance of the node.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).